# Hover on Menu dropdown - How to make Hover effect not to disappear?

Tags: html, css

I have some serious problem with my menu and its hover effect.

I have a very basic menu, which has a submenu:

```
<ul id="menu">
 <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu2</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">SubMenu1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">SubMenu2</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the CSS I'm using:

```
#menu li {
 display: inline;
}

#menu li a {
 padding: 10px;
}

#menu li a:hover {
 background: #000;
}

#menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#menu ul ul {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #000;
}
```

Okay, so my problem is, that when I hover my mouse the Dropdown menu and gets my mouse on the Submenus, the Hover effect of the Parent menu item (in this case Menu2) is disappearing. So it will not have black BG when I hover the mouse on the submenu items.

Is there anything I could do to make that hover effect stay on the partent menu (Menu2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem: your selectors are wrong.

`#menu` IS an `ul` , then `#menu ul ul` means

> an `ul` *descendant* of an `ul` *descendant* of my `#menu`, that is an `ul`

You don't have three levels of `ul`s, so...

change `ul ul` to `li ul`.

The second problem is that you are affecting `a` tag on hover, but `a` tag is a **sibling**, not an **ancestor** (or parent) of your submenu `ul`.

You should then target your `li`, not your `a`.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/mSrkn/ (with tons of problems still there, but with the two above resolved)

```
#menu li {
 display: inline;
}

#menu li a {
 padding: 10px;
}

#menu li:hover {
 background: #000;
}

#menu li ul {
    display: none;
}
#menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#menu li ul {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with yout selectors:

```
#menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

This says that any element with ID that has a child ul with lis that's hovered with a child ul should be selected. Your markup is different from this, the UL itself is the ID #menu so you have to remove the first ul from the selectors themselves:

```
#menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V7Ltw/

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seems to solve my problem. I have tried and everything has remained the same :(

Comment: #menu ul li > ul:hover TRy that too

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding the following to your CSS

```
#menu li:hover{
    background-color: #000;
}
```

By hovering over the sub-menu, you're still hovering over the parent list item.

And you should follow Kyle's answer as well as you do need to remove the first UL selector from your css.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change a lot of stuff to make this work, the basic idea is to put the submenu inside your menu items :

CSS:

```
#menu li {
 display: inline;
}

#menu li a {
 padding: 10px;
}

#menu li a:hover {
 background: #000;
}

#menu ul.submenu {
    display: none;
    float: left;   // For viewing purpose
}

#menu ul.submenu { padding: 20px; }

#menu ul.submenu:hover { 
   display: block; 
}

#menu li:hover > ul.submenu {
   display: block;
}

ul.submenu:hover + a { background: #000; }

#menu ul {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
 <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
 <li>
   <ul class='submenu'>
   <li><a href="#">SubMenu1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">SubMenu2</a></li>
  </ul>
   <a href="#">Menu2</a>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/V7Ltw/